# Correct method of using eval() when returning values passed as string parameters

Tags: javascript, string, eval, calculator

I passed **string** parameters to **calculate()** function. I need them to be returned as calculated value. In which of below forms I used **eval()** correctly?

**Data:**

```
var nums = ['2','3','1'], sum = ['+'];
```

**First version:**

```
function calculate(a,b,c,d,e)
{
        console.log('Calculating...(plus separators): '+a+' '+b+' '+c+' '+d+' '+e);
        console.log('Calculating...(comma separators): ',a,' ',b,' ',c,' ',d,' ',e);

        console.log('a :',a);
        console.log('b :',b);
        console.log('c :',c);
        console.log('d :',d);
        console.log('e :',e);
    return eval(a+b+c+d+e);
};
console.log('RESULT: ',calculate(nums[0],sum[0], nums[1],sum[0], nums[2]));
```

**Second version:**

```
function calculateP(a,c,e)
{
        console.log('Calculating...(plus separators): '+a+' '+c+' '+e);
        console.log('Calculating...(comma separators): ',a,' ',c,' ',e);

        console.log('a: ',a);
        console.log('c: ',c);
        console.log('e: ',e);
    return eval(a+c+e);
};
console.log('precise RESULT: ',calculateP(nums[0], nums[1], nums[2]));
```

**Console** shows **"RESULT: 6"** and **"precise RESULT: 231"**.

Which one is correct, if any is? In my opinion the first one (**"RESULT 6"**) is ok, but i'd rather to be sure.

**P.S** I used **eval()**, cause originally i will be passing math expression as string "2+3-(4*3)/7" and want it to be calculated. Some kind of simple calculator parser

**P.S #2** I used arrays, cause eventually I am going to pass more array elements to this function.

**__________________________________________________________________________**

**EDIT**

Is it now correctly used **eval()**?

```
function plus(a,b) {
  return a+b;
}

function minus(a,b) {
  return a-b;
}

var expression = 'minus(plus(2, 3),minus(5,3))';

console.log('(2+3)-(5-3) ',eval(expression));

    expression = 'plus(plus(2, 3),minus(5,3))';

console.log('(2+3)+(5-3) ',eval(expression));
```

Comment: Using `eval()` is almost never a good idea. Plus, it's not clear why you believe you need `eval()` at all.

Comment: Why do you think you need to use `eval` to solve this?

Comment: I'am coding simple calculator parser in JS, so I considered results should be calulated by **eval()**, because what is other way, to use operators like: **'+', '-', '*', '/'**  in strict way? The original expression to be "decoded" and calculated will be such as **'2+3-(4*3)/7"**. I split it into chars and then (after few functions recognizing all symbols) it will be calculated as string. So i need to pass also math operators as string, not standard "plus, minus, divide, multiply"  JS (or other language)o perators. I want all to be calculated from initial string mathemical expression.

Comment: You write a parser (it's not too hard for simple math like you have described), thereby avoiding the use of `eval` and any security issues that go hand-in-hand with it. I believe [math.js](http://mathjs.org/) does exactly this (but handles quite complex math), so you could take a look at their source code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I really believe that you can avoid `eval` nearly everywhere, but if you do something which is bad - do it good!

```
var expression = '2 + 3 - (4 * 3) / 7';

console.log(eval(expression));
```

Mathematical operations? Easy!

```
function cos(input) {
  return Math.cos(input);
}

function ln(input) {
  return Math.log(input);
}

var expression = '2 + 3 - cos(4 * 3) / ln(7)';

console.log(eval(expression));
```

What you are doing with eval is absolutely weird and going against eval's nature.

Comment: Look, i want this **expression* var to be split into array of chars. Then in loop JS approaches '+', '-' and so on and i want it to know that it should be addition and substraction operations. So i don't want to strictly do '+' and '-' but need JS to interpret char '+' as plus operator. I think that's idea of parser? I absolutely don't insist on eval(), but i thought  my problem could be solved by eval(). 
Briefly i want JS "inter alia" to recognize math symbols in expression given as string to be parsed like a caluculator does it.

Comment: You asked a question which is called "Correct method of using eval() when returning values passed as string parameters". You did not ask a question named "How to write a parser in JavaScript". So, I answered your question: your eval is not used correctly. If you want to solve your problem ask a proper question or directly go to e.g. https://github.com/josdejong/mathjs and look how *they* do it

Comment: This demonstrates `eval`ing the expression as a whole string (this seems better than your current idea), there is nothing stopping you from splitting the string into some kind of array (for whatever purpose).

Comment: I think i'll go this way http://jsbin.com/ladevifabu/edit?js,console (coded quickly just to show my idea) **Is it better than my "eval() idea"?** It's about "loop through array of chars, if find numbers between which is some math operator, execute appropriate function". So the result is 2+3=5, cause first nums and operator is '2+3'.

Comment: @smnbbrv could you explain me how to transform you code to work with my example? `function plus(a,b) {
  return a+b;
}

function minus(a,b) {
  return a-b;
}

var expression = 'plus(2, 3)+minus(5,3)';

console.log(eval(expression));`

Comment: @Chris92 the code with eval is a wrong one. A really wrong one. What you need to do is to dynamically build the solution tree for every expression where the root of the tree would be your solution and the leaves will be top level operations (e.g. expressions in `()` or multiply / dividing expressions) The implementation does not really need an actual tree structure, it could be also done with recursions or using stack data structure. In fact you need to write a light version of a compiler which requires lots of time and some knowledge.

Comment: you can also look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7343504/possible-to-write-a-compiler-with-javascript , it may be really helpful to use some third-party tools

Answer (score 1):

Hi you have to use like below:

```
var nums = ['2','3','1'], sum = ['+']; 
function calculate(nums)
{
  var res =0;
  for(var i=0;i<nums.length;i++){
    res= res+(parseInt(nums[i]));
  }
    return res;
};

 console.log('RESULT: ',calculate(nums))
```

Comment: What is the difference between using eval() as I did and your code?

Comment: eval() used for execute a string ex:var a=5,b=10; var temp = "a+b";eval(temp) will print 15 more info refer:http://api.jquery.com/jquery.globaleval/

Comment: Ok, but what if i want JS to recognize given expression like "2+3-(4*3)/7", if it finds '+' then it knows that it's addition operator, and then it executes appropriate function. I don't want just to do that strict in function, like "return 2+3", i want JS to recognize that '+' is sum and then do addition operation. I hope it's clear what i want to do.

Comment: And you did just string parsing into int, without even calculating it :) I want JS to recognize given math operators (in expression give as string) and then calculate it, but it's important for me to recognize '+' is addition, '-' is substraction, '/' is divide, and so on

Answer (score 1):

Just an example how to deal with a string and some values without `eval()`.

```js
var operators = {
        '+': function (a, i) {
            a[i - 1] += a.splice(i, 2)[1];
            return true;
        },
        '*': function (a, i) {
            a[i - 1] *= a.splice(i, 2)[1];
            return true;
        },
        '(': function (a, i) {
            var j = i + 1,
                b;

            while (j < a.length) {
                if (a[j] === ')') {
                    b = a.splice(i + 1, j - i);
                    b.pop();
                    a[i] = calculate(b);
                    return true;
                }
                if (a[j] === '(') {
                    return false;
                }
                j++;
            }
        },
        ')': 0
    },
    precedence = ['(', '*', '+'];

function split(s) {
    var a = s.split(''),
        i = 1;

    while (i < a.length) {
        if (!(a[i - 1] in operators || a[i] in operators)) {
            a[i - 1] += a.splice(i, 1)[0];
            continue;
        }
        i++;
    }
    return a.map(function (b) {
        return b in operators ? b : Number(b);
    });
}

function calculate(a) {
    while (a.length > 1) {
        precedence.some(function (b) {
            return a.some(function (c, i) {
                if (b === c) {
                    return operators[b](a, i);
                }
            });
        });
    }
    return a[0];
}

document.write(calculate(split('12+23*37')) + '<br>'); // 863
document.write(calculate(split('12+23*(2+(3*4)+5)*37')) + '<br>'); // 16181
```

Comment: Looks too complicated for me. But i appreciate your proposition to avoid `eval()`